# Laravel installation errors on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel

Followed documentation on laravel.com. Installed Vagrant 2.0.1 first. Then installed Virtualbox 5.2.2, Homestead and Composer. After typing

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

I get this:

```
Changed current directory to /home/ml/.config/composer
Using version ^1.5 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.5 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.5.0].
    - laravel/installer v1.5.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Comment: Install the ext-zip extension. `apt-get install php7.1-zip`. If you do not use PHP version 7.1, change the version value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the ext-zip extension.

`apt-get install php7.1-zip`

Then just restart PHP and test.
`sudo service php7.1 restart`

If you do not use PHP version 7.1, change the version value.